# How to make this carousel work right?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, responsive

I've made this carousel (image slider) a few years ago and it was working properly until now. I'd like to make it responsive. The problem is that I set the picture's width 100% but the javascript change the parent div's width five times bigger when it put the pictures next to each other therefore the picture(s) is also become bigger and hazy. I spent my whole day to find out how can I solve this so I hope you can help me! :) Thanks a lot!

```js
    function carousel() {   
        var speed = 3000;
        var timer = setInterval("rotate()", speed);
        var tabs_number = $(".tab").length;
        var tab_width = $(".tab").outerWidth();
        var offset = tab_width * (-1);
        var total_width = $("#tabs").width = tab_width * tabs_number;   
        var first_tab = $(".tab:first");    
        var last_tab = $(".tab:last");
        $("#tabs").css({"width" : total_width});
        last_tab.insertBefore(first_tab);
        $("#tabs").css({"left" : offset});
        first_tab.addClass("active");   
        $("#nav-right").click(function() {
            var active_tab = $(".active");
            active_tab.removeClass("active");
            active_tab.next().addClass("active");
            var left_indent = parseInt($("#tabs").css("left")) - tab_width;
            $("#tabs:not(:animated)").animate({"left" : left_indent},500,function () {
                    // az elsőt berakjuk az utolsó mögé
                    $("#tabs div:first").insertAfter($("#tabs div:last"));
                    $("#tabs").css({"left" : offset});
            });     
        });
        $("#nav-left").click(function() {
            var active_tab = $(".active");
            active_tab.removeClass("active");
            active_tab.prev().addClass("active");
            var left_indent = parseInt($("#tabs").css("left")) + tab_width;
            $("#tabs:not(:animated)").animate({"left" : left_indent},500,function(){
                $(".tab:last").insertBefore($(".tab:first"));
                $("#tabs").css({"left" : offset});
            });     
        });
        $("#tabs, #nav-left, #nav-right").hover(
            function() { clearInterval(timer); },
            function() { timer = setInterval("rotate()", speed); }
        );
    };
    function rotate() {
        $("#nav-right").click();
    }
    
    
    // Client code
    $(document).ready(function() {
        carousel();
    });
```

```css
    div#wrapper
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 220px); 
        float: left;
        margin: 120px auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    div.nav-buttons
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;   
        float: left;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    div#nav-left,
    div#nav-right
    {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100%;   
        background-size: 40px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50%;   
        z-index: 2; 
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    div#nav-left
    {
        background-image: url('images/icons/left.png'); 
    }

    div#nav-right
    {
        background-image: url('images/icons/right.png');    
    }

    div#nav-left:hover,
    div#nav-right:hover
    {
        background-color: rgba(52, 73, 94,0.5);
    }

    div#tabs 
    {   
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    div.tab
    {
        width: 100%;    
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50%;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="nav-buttons">
            <div id="nav-left" title="Előző"></div>
            <div id="nav-right" title="Következő"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs">
            <div d="tab-first" class="tab"></div>
            <div id="tab-second" class="tab"></div>
            <div id="tab-third" class="tab"></div>      
            <div id="tab-fourth" class="tab"></div>     
            <div id="tab-fifth" class="tab"></div>      
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please consider to provide a working code snippet. The one above won't run as jQuery is not properly referenced.

Comment: The first javasricpt file ("jquery-3.1.1.min.js") is a basic link for jquery. You can use this also: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Sure, but as it is a local reference, it does not make the snippet working.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I missed width: 100%; height: 100%; properties for div#tabs. I've edited the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! Thanks everything!

```js
function carousel() {

 // sebesség
 var speed = 3000;

 // időzítő
 var timer = setInterval("rotate()", speed);

 // képek száma
 var images_number = $(".tab").length;

 // carousel teljes szélessége
 var carousel_width = $("#tabs").width() * images_number; 

 // a képeket tartalmazó DIV szélessége megegyezik a carousel teljes szélességével
 
 var wrapper_width = $("#wrapper").width();
 
 $("#tabs").css({"width": carousel_width});

 // az első képre rátesszük az active class-t
 $(".tab:first").addClass("active"); 

 // következő gombra történő kattintás
 $("#nav-right").click(function(){

  // aktív képet léptetjük eggyel
  $active_image = $("#tabs div.active").next();  

  // ha nincs több kép akkor visszaugrunk az elsőre
  if ($active_image.length==0){
   $active_image = $("#tabs div:first");   
  }

  // léptetést végrehajtó függvény hívása
  step();
 });


 // előző gombra történő kattintás
 $("#nav-left").click(function(){

  // aktív képet léptetjük eggyel vissza
  $active_image = $("#tabs div.active").prev();
  
  // ha nincs több kép akkor visszaugrunk az utolsóra
  if ($active_image.length==0){
   $active_image = $("#tabs div:last");   
  }

  // léptetést végrehajtó függvény hívása
  step();
 });

 // ha az egeret a kép vagy a gombok fölé mozgatjuk, megállítjuk az automatikus léptetést
 $("#tabs, #nav-left, #nav-right").hover(
  // a clearInterval() metódus törli a setInterval() által beállított időzítőt
  function() { clearInterval(timer); },

  // a setInterval() metódussal meghívjuk a rotate() függvényt a speed változóban meghatározott időközönként
  function() { timer = setInterval("rotate()", speed); }
 );
}

// léptetést végrehajtó függvény
function step() {

 // össze képről leszedjük az active class-t
 $("#tabs div").removeClass("active");

 // aktív képre rátesszük az active class-t
 $active_image.addClass("active"); 

 /* Meghatározzuk az eltolás mértékét amit úgy kapunk meg,
    hogy az akutális kép indexét beszorozzuk a kép méretével.
    Jelen esetben 800px egy kép szélessége, ezért az eltolás
    mértéke így fog alakulni: 0, 800, 1600, 2400, 3200...
 */
 var imagesposition = $active_image.index() * $("#tabs div").width();

 // images DIV-et eltoljuk az imageposition változóban meghatározott értékkel
 $("#tabs:not(:animated)").animate({"left": -imagesposition}, 500);
}

// automatikus léptetést végző függvény
function rotate() {
 $("#nav-right").click();
}
```

```css
div#wrapper
{
 width: 100%;
 height: calc(100% - 220px); 
 float: left;
 margin: 120px auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #3498db;
 position: relative; 
}

div.nav-buttons
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%; 
 float: left;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

div#nav-left,
div#nav-right
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100%; 
 background-size: 40px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%; 
 z-index: 2; 
 cursor: pointer;
}

div#nav-left
{
 background-image: url('images/icons/left.png'); 
}

div#nav-right
{
 background-image: url('images/icons/right.png'); 
}

div#nav-left:hover,
div#nav-right:hover
{
 background-color: rgba(52, 73, 94,0.5);
}

div#tabs 
{ 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background: orange; 
}

div.tab
{
 width: calc(100% / 5); 
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
 background-size: cover; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%;
}

div#tab-first
{
 background-image: url('../pics/1.jpg');
}

div#tab-second
{
 background-image: url('../pics/2.jpg');
}

div#tab-third
{
 background-image: url('../pics/3.jpg');
}

div#tab-fourth
{
 background-image: url('../pics/4.jpg');
}

div#tab-fifth
{
 background-image: url('../pics/5.jpg');
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="nav-buttons">
            <div id="nav-left" title="Előző"></div>
            <div id="nav-right" title="Következő"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs">
            <div id="tab-first" class="tab"></div>
            <div id="tab-second" class="tab"></div>
            <div id="tab-third" class="tab"></div>      
            <div id="tab-fourth" class="tab"></div>     
            <div id="tab-fifth" class="tab"></div>      
        </div>
    </div>
```